# Regular express for whitespace with Quotes

Tags: python, regex

I have Paragraph below.

> Python is an interpreted, high-level, general-purpose programming language. "Created by Guido " van Rossum and first released in 1991, Python's " design philosophy" emphasizes code readability with its notable use of significant whitespace.

I want to write a code in python which will find if there is any whitespace after opening of quote and whitespace before ending of closing quote.

In above paragraph example "Created by Guido " and " design philosophy" should be shown as errors in paragraph.

Regex will really help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please show what you’ve tried so far and where you’ve gotten stuck?  What research have you done already?

Comment: This question lacks focus on the specific programming problem you encountered when you tried this yourself. Also, restricting the solution to regex is unwise, though probably possible. Please explain the reason for preferring regex mechanisms.

Comment: Please provde more sample input, in order to prevent oversimplified answers which simply match any `"`. For that you need sample input which also contains `"` which should NOT be matched.

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest the following approach, which makes two passes over the input:

```
inp = """Python is an "interpreted", high-level, general-purpose programming language. "Created by Guido " van Rossum and first released in 1991, Python's " design philosophy" emphasizes code readability with its notable use of significant whitespace."""
inp = re.sub(r'"\S[^"]*\S"', '', inp)
matches = re.findall(r'"\s+[^"]+"|"[^"]+\s+"', inp)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
['"Created by Guido "', '" design philosophy"']
```

The strategy here is to find all matching quoted terms which either start or end with whitespace.  You may assert the `matches` array above, and check whether it be empty (no invalid quoted terms), or non empty (such invalid quoted terms are present).

Answer (score 1):

You would probably need to do something like this:

```
re = regex.compile('"\s[^"]*"|"\s[^"]*\s"|"[^"]*\s"')
re.findall(YOUR_STR)
```

It's actually a fairly naive approach simply look for any pair of `"` with zero or more non-`"` characters between them and assume they are the opening/closing one in that pair. Then look for patterns where former, both, or latter is followed by a white space.